# Segger J-tag vs J-link

Tags: microcontroller, jtag, j-link

Are Segger J-tag and J-link the same thing or are these two different things? I could not find helpful answers yet.

Comment: Do you mean JTAG by "J-tag"?

Comment: JTAG is a standardized interface provided for example by Segger J-Link (and other vendors too). ARM microcontrollers uses SWD which is a "light version" of JTAG.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think a product named *"Segger J-tag"* exists.

There is a product named **Segger J-link** which is a **JTAG** and SWD debug probe.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you mean JTAG by "J-tag" and [Segger J-Link](https://www.segger.com/products/debug-probes/j-link/) than: No, they are not the same by a far stretch.

[JTAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JTAG) is an interface that allows programming and debugging of integrated circuits while mounted on a PCB.

J-Link is a series of debug probes (hardware devices that can use different interfaces to programm and debug circuits). J-Link can use different interfaces like SPI or JTAG to perform this task.

Answer (score 1):

As @Klas-Kenny has already mentioned, I can't find any Segger product called *Segger J-tag*.

There are *Segger J-Trace* products, which compared to a *Segger J-Link* add ETM trace capability.

The tables of different product capabilities I'm aware of are in:

- [Debug & Trace Probes](https://www.segger.com/products/debug-trace-probes/)
- [Flasher in-circuit programmers](https://www.segger.com/products/flasher-in-circuit-programmer/)

Answer (score 0):

For reference: **J-Tag** is like **Car** where as **Segger J-link** is like **Audi** and **J-link Pro** is like **Audi R8**